# How to slide out a div at a certain position

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

I have a div that I am sliding out when a label is hovered on.

HTML:

```
<div class="cellDataViewTdmStatus divCell userSitesCol7">
    <label class="lblViewTdmStatus">View Status</label>
</div>


<div id="tdmStatus" class="hidden flyout">
    LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET<br>
    Blah blah blah
</div>
```

Here is what the label's div looks like on the page (note the "View Status" text on the right - that's the label in the code above):

[image: example of page]

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }

.flyout {
width: 560px;
height: 56px;
background-color: #EFF7DF;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
border: solid 1px #CC6600;
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 10000;
top: 100px;
right: 300px;   }
```

JS:

```
$('.lblViewTdmStatus').hover(function() {
    $('.flyout').toggle("slide", {direction:'right'});
});
```

This *functions* as needed (slides out from hidden) when the label is hovered on.

I need the div to slide out in such a way that it looks like it is coming from the border to the left of the "View Status" label.

Additionally, this is a table in which each row will have a label to hover over, so I need the sliding div to slide out to the left of the label that was clicked on.

Comment: You need to find the offset (left and top) of the link clicked and place your slide accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to putvande's nudge in the right direction.

I just viewed the position.left and position.top values of the clicked label, then made adjustments to that value until it was positioned where I wanted it (to the left of the label clicked). I also had to removed the "top" and "right" properties from the CSS.

Here's the new js code:

```
$('.lblViewTdmStatus').hover(function() {
var position = $(this).position(),
    left = position.left,
    top = position.top,
    divLeft = position.left - 590,
    divTop = position.top - 50;
//console.log('position.left: ' + position.left + ' position.top: ' + position.top);

$('.flyout').css('top',divTop).css('left',divLeft);
$('.flyout').toggle('slide', {direction:'right'});
});
```